# NotSupportedError: pranswer not yet implemented

Tags: webrtc

When i use webrtc with pranswer state in firefox 41 , there is a error : NotSupportedError: pranswer not yet implemented.

Comment: I had try Firefox Nightly 45 , it also has this error.

Comment: It's not yet implemented, as it says. Do you have a question?

Comment: What version of Firefox will implement pranswer or how can i release renegotiation in webrtc instead of pranswer ?

Comment: It is tracked in [bug 1004510](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004510) with medium priority. Patches welcome. What do you mean "release renegotiation"? What problem are you trying to solve that requires pranswer?